# how to put more than 2 conditions in Query binding parameters

Tags: php, mysql, sql, parameters, phalcon

Hi Im working on parameter binding query Phalcon. Following is my code

```
$conditions = "client = :client: AND inv_date = :inv_date: AND date_sent = :date_sent: AND date_received = :date_received:";
        $parameters = array(
            "client" => $search_client,
            "inv_date" => $invoice_date,
            "date_sent" => $date_sent,
            "date_received" => $date_received
        );
$invoices = Invoices::find(
    array(
        $conditions,
        "bind" => $parameters
    )
);
```

Do I have use the AND correctly??
FYI its not working, if I try the following, it works:

```
$conditions = "client = :client: AND inv_date = :inv_date:";
$parameters = array(
    "client" => $search_client,
);
$invoices = Invoices::find(
    array(
        $conditions,
        "bind" => $parameters
    )
);
```

All the fields exist in table, I think there is other way to use multiple AND

Comment: This is the correct way. Both of your examples use same technique, so my guess is that there are no records matching your first query conditions. 

There is other way to use multiple conditions, its the Phalcon Query Builder. Query builder example:

`$robots = Robots::query()
    ->where("type = :type:")
    ->andWhere("year < 2000")
    ->bind(array("type" => "mechanical"))
    ->order("name")
    ->execute();`

Comment: @NikiMihaylov, Thanks man

Comment: You can solve question by marking your answer, so others can use it.

Comment: query is correct. One of your query parameter is `empty`. I guess its returning empty object.

Answer (score 1):

```
$conditions = "client = :client: AND inv_date = :inv_date:";
$parameters = array(
    "client" => $search_client,
);
$invoices = Invoices::find(
    array(
        $conditions,
        "bind" => $parameters
    )
);
```

This code doesn't work because you pass just one parameter client, but have to pass 2 parameters: client and inv_date.

```
$parameters = array(
    "client" => $search_client,
    "inv_date" => $invoice_date,
);
```

Hence - you can use this option (because it really works) or you can use `andWhere` like @Niki Mihaylov advised.